# Why my awk to extract a column in CSV have a trailing double quote?

Tags: macos, shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file like this.

```
"cnt","phr"
"3679650","URL1"
"844588","URL2"
"572854","URL3"
"469274","URL4"
```

I googled and found this command.

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' test.csv
```

I get this result

```
URL1"
URL2"
URL3"
URL4"
```

How do I just get?

```
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```

I'm using OSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command with field separator as comma or double quote:

```
awk -F '[",]+' 'NR>1{print $3}' file.csv

URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```

Or else use `gsub` with comma as field separator

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{gsub(/"/, ""); print $2}' file.csv

URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative to `awk`

```
$ tr -d '"' <file | cut -d, -f2 | sed 1d
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```

**Explanation:** delete quotes, select second field using comma delimiter, drop first row

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that quote is because it's not your field separator. Your defined FS contains a comma.

There are complicated regexes available to use awk for CSV data, but I usually recommend a proper CSV parser to parse CSV data. Ruby has one that's easy to work with:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts row[1]}' file
```

which outputs

```
phr
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
```